# CSS align challenge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using a bootstrap 3.3.7 navbar with 3 groups of items :

- A) on the left (1 item),
- B) centered (4 items),
- C) on the right (1 item)

So I have :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav tabs">
            <!-- A) here are the left aligned LIs (float: left) -->
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <!-- C) here are the right aligned LIs (float: right) -->
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center tabs">
            <!-- B) here are the right aligned LIs (float: none; text-align: center; font-size:0) -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

As asked in the comments, here is my CSS :

```
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.navbar-right {
    float: right!important;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-center > li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing it : https://jsfiddle.net/m5s8ov8j/ (please drag'n drop the JSFiddle centered vertical separator to the left to see the result as Bootstrap turns the nevbar into a hamburger menu).

Now I'm asked to insert a new group of 2 items between groups (B) and (C) with 2 conditions :

- group (B) (centered) must remain centered,
- the new group must be centered between the LAST item of (B) and the FIRST item of (C).

How can I do so ?

Comment: Please include your CSS

Comment: can u provide code with jsfiddle?

Comment: I took in account all your comments (css, jsfiddle) and updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with CSS alone, but here's a solution with JavaScript. Position the new UL absolutely, then determine what its location should be.
I put this in the onresize event, so that the location will remain correct when the user makes the window wider or narrower.

```js
window.onresize = function() {

var cenUL = document.querySelector('.navbar-default .navbar-collapse ul.navbar-center li:last-child');
var rightUL = document.querySelector('.navbar-default .navbar-collapse ul.navbar-right li:first-child');
var newUL = document.getElementById('new');
newUL.style.left = ((cenUL.offsetLeft+cenUL.offsetWidth+rightUL.offsetLeft-newUL.offsetWidth)/2)+'px';
};

window.onresize();
```

```css
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-center > li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
#new {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav tabs">
      <li>
        <a href="/">MyWebsite</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="">Menu</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul id="new" class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="">NEW!</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
      <li>
        <a href="">Company</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to make a area visible on xs, you can use **[bootstrap responsive classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)**

**[Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/9uCDBHZ5oC)**

**HTML**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav tabs">
      <li>
        <a href="/">MyWebsite</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="">Menu</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right visible-xs">  // <-- HERE
      <li>
        <a href="">New Group Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">New Group Item 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
      <li>
        <a href="">Company</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: All items must have the same visibility. Thx for your tip.